# Show that $f(a+t\cdot m) \equiv f(a) \pmod m$

Tags: number-theory

Following problem:

> Given the polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients. If $a, t\in\Bbb Z$ and $m\in\Bbb N$, show that:
>   $$f(a+t\cdot m) \equiv f(a) \pmod m$$

No idea how to start with that. If I put in the general form of polynomials for $f$ I don't get far sadly. A tip would help! :)

Comment: Consider $(a+t\cdot m)^n\mod{m}$. Once you've calculated this, then the rest should be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ring $\Bbb Z_m$ we have $$a+t\cdot m\equiv_ma$$ In particular $$(a+t\cdot m)^k\equiv_m a^k$$
for every $k\in\Bbb N$.

Let $f(a)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}c_ia^i$, then $$f(a+t\cdot m)\equiv_m \sum_{i=0}^{n}c_i(a+t\cdot m)^i\\\equiv_m \sum_{i=0}^{n}c_ia^i\\\equiv_m f(a)$$

Answer (score 1):

$(x+tm)^n-x^n
=tm\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+tm)^kx^{n-1-k}
\equiv 0 \bmod m$

Answer (score 1):

You just need to show that $m$ divides $f(a +tm) - f(a)$, which is easy once you consider any polynomial with integer coefficients, as $$f(a + tm)- f(a) = c_0(a + tm) + \dots c_n(a+tm)^n - c_0 a - \dots c_na^n$$
 which is divisible by $m$.

(Terms that remain after the binomial expansions in above expression are all multiples of $m$.)

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ we have $ab\equiv \bar ab\equiv \bar a\bar b \pmod{m}$

Indeed $a=\bar a+k_1m$ and $b=\bar b+k_2m$ then

$\begin{align}ab&=\bar ab+m(k_1b)\\&=\bar a\bar b+m(k_1\bar b+k_2\bar a+k_1k_2m)\end{align}$

This property passes directly to polynomial by induction, since $a^2=aa=\bar a\bar a=\bar a^2$ and $a^{n+1}=a^na=\bar a^na=\bar a^n\bar a=\bar a^{n+1}$

Once we have this for monomials, it is straightforward that $P(a)\equiv P(\bar a)\pmod{m}$ for any polynomial $P$ since it is a linear combination of monomials.